# Redirected folders: Missing files during a domain change. Where are they?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, user-profile

I need start by explaining the scenario and then I'll ask the questions.

Sunday evening all redirected folders are copied and placed on a NAS to be accessed Monday morning to restore user files.

Monday morning every employee shows up to work to find that there is a new server cluster running a new domain that every computer needs to be joined to. The old setup was using redirected folders for desktop and my documents to an SBS2011 server. The new setup is not using redirected folders. As IT staff and contractors race around to get everyone added to the new domain Monday morning, someone creates and saves a file on their desktop before being added to the new domain. The IT person (who shall not be named) does not backup the user's files and moves them to the new domain.

Here is where the problem is. The IT person copies down the user files from the NAS and thinks the job is done. However, the user cannot find that one file he/she created that morning. Going to c:\users\old_username doesn't show desktop or my documents because they were redirected. But since the computer could not reach the SBS2011 server, the file never got redirected either. SO, where is it?!

Answer (score 0):

did the IT guy delete the old local Username ? if not Have you tried logging in as the "old_username"? not using the domain  but using computername\old_local_username .